# encrypted url in base64

Tags: php, video, base64, picasa

i find a code to encrypt video url but only if the file is end with .mp4

so i want to make the code to work with picasa links i can do what or not??

```
<video controls> 
   <source type="video/mp4 src="<?php echo getEncodedVideoString('mp4', 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/g2XMA9zsuKNRjLnid599v6HfYI-Io1TZaUDJUJskCp8=m22');?>"> 
</video>


<?php
function getEncodedVideoString($type, $file) { 
   return 'data:video/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)); 
}
?>
```

Comment: [Base64 is not encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).

Comment: ok is not encrypted but still don't get the real url, you can help me to make this code to work because i don't understand how to do with BLAKE2 or SHA256 is too op for me..